# Using re.VERBOSE on a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

How would I go about taking the following regular expression:

```
re.compile(r'(\'?(("(\"|[^"])*")|^#.*\n|;.*\n|\(|\)|-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|[a-zA-Z-#][a-zA-Z0-9.+-/\!]*))|\'.*')
```

and writing it across multiple lines?

For whatever reason my attempts at using `re.VERBOSE` seem to change the value of the expression.

Comment: You should tag the language you’re using

Answer (score 1):

If you put two strings next to each other, with only whitespace between them,  then the python interpreter will concatenate them

```
re.compile(r'(\'?(("(\"|[^"])")|^#.\n|;.\n|(|)|-?[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?|'
           r'[a-zA-Z-#][a-zA-Z0-9.+-/!]))|\'.*')
```

Comment: Ah! My hero! My Python is shaky, but I had the same thought earlier. For whatever reason it didn't work (typo perhaps). Since you suggested it I figured I would try it again, and well, it didn't work. But at that point I was pretty confident it should work, so I tried the same thing a third time and it worked. I suppose this just goes to show that tired coding is bad coding.

Answer (score 0):

When converting your regex to `re.VERBOSE` mode make sure that:

- whitespace is escaped or replaced with some equivalent: `\s` or `[ ]` or `'\ '` (I had to put `''` here due to SO formatting). 
  All plain whitespace is ignored with `re.VERBOSE`.
- hashes `#` are escaped or replaced the same way: `\#`, etc.
  Hashes work as commenting means with `re.VERBOSE`.

Then you can rewrite your regex using python's multiline strings:

```
import re
re.compile(r'''
    (\'?(("(\"|[^"])*")
         |^\#.*\n
         |;.*\n
         |\(
         |\)
         |-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?
         |[a-zA-Z-#][a-zA-Z0-9.+-/\!]*
        )
    )
    |\'.*
    ''', re.VERBOSE)
```